# Foreign Key em outro banco de dados?

Tags: mysql

Dúvida em MySQL...

Quais são os possíveis problemas que podem acarretar ao fazer uma Chave estrangeira em bancos de dados diferentes?

Levando a consideração este tipo de chave estrangeira e uma View que busca as informações de outro banco de dados, qual é mais útil?

Comment: Até onde saiba isto não é possível , já implementei isto mas fazendo triggers de validação para fazer o controle de FK.

Answer (score 2):

sobre a primeira pergunta, chave estrangeira em outro database, o que é permitido é fazer um atributo com o mesmo nome e usar o valor de indice igual na outra database, mas o mysql não permite criar relacionamento entre databases diferentes, então não garante integridade entre as tabelas de diferentes databases ok.

Sobre a segunda pergunta, quando usar chaves primárias/estrangeiras ou atributo indexado irá ganhar tempo na busca pela informação quando usar um deles no filtro ( na condição where ).

Sobre a view é usada para consultas onde você deseja "limitar" os atributos, ocultando algumas informações que talvez tu não deseja que seja visualizado por determinado usuário, para ganhar em performance na hora de fazer uma busca de muita informação/complexidade, utiliza-se "stored procedure".

Answer (score 0):

Sobre sua primeira pergunta, não é possível utilizar nenhuma chave estrangeira em duas bases diferentes, nenhum engine do MySQL (database que eu conheço, myISAM e etc... Não sei te dizer se outra database com base sql permite) permite que faça-se tal relacionamento mesmo que sejam da mesma linguagem e engine (MySQL usando myISAM por exemplo), e nem é orientado a fazer isso também, caso você precise que algo seja consultado de forma exterior é orientado o uso de webservices e caso algum dado / tabela precise de consulta em alguma database diferente é porque algum erro na modelagem da mesma foi cometido, pois isso fere as boas práticas de modelagem de dados (para saber mais procure as NF's de database no google).

Sobre a segunda pergunta a stored procedure é uma mão na roda para caso você tenha uma query por exemplo com muitos joins, relacionamentos de tabelas e derivados, ele agiliza o processo de busca  e permite você evitar muita reescrita de código e dependendo de qual linguagem que você está utilizando para desenvolvimento back end junto com o seu server side você pode usar o memcache que ajuda ainda mais.

Sobre as views, é apenas criar restrições para sua base de dados de visualização dos dados que irão ser apresentados para o mesmo (aquele user que define na string de conexão com a base de dados).

Espero ter te ajudado e dado uma resposta parcialmente satisfatória.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei se isso é uma boa prática na administração de banco de dados, mas já fiz isso no `MySQL` e funciona (pelo menos usando o innodb).

Imagine o seguinte senário:

```
banco1
 - tabelaX (codigo_exemplo_pk)

banco2
 - tabelaY (codigo_exemplo_fk)
```

O relacionamento ficaria assim:

```
ALTER TABLE banco2.tabelaY ADD FOREIGN KEY (codigo_exemplo_fk) REFERENCES banco1.tabelaX(codigo_exemplo_pk_pk) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Você pode conferir se o relacoinamento está apontando realmente para a tabela (Pai) com um `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
show create table banco2.tabelaY;
```